# can we list the software installed in the OS using JAVA

Tags: java, operating-system

I want to develop an application in which I want to change the database as per the system.

For ex: I would to connect the Java code to .mdf file if MS-Office is installed or using `orathin` if Oracle is installed.
This will help me not to specify the database and decrease my dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is No.  There is no standard way to do this, and I'm not aware of any 3rd-party libraries that do this.

---

The more detailed answer is that you could *in theory* write your own code to do this, but the code would be non-portable and unreliable.

- On Windows, you'd need to interogate the Registry.
- On Linux, you'd need to check the *obvious* places that the software might be installed, and hope that the admin / user hadn't decided to do it differently.

---

And even if you can accurately determine what software (of relevance to you) is installed, you've got more problems.

- What if there are two database products installed?  What if none?
- What if the user wants to use a non-local RDBMS?
- What about the other database-related configuration?  Database account/password?   Connection URLs?  Logical database and table names?
- Etcetera.

In short, I'm doubtful that you'll be able to design an automatic installation strategy that works well enough for a large percentage of your users.

Answer (score 1):

You can try probing for the application required: identify the operating system then crawl through the directories where you expect the application to be installed (%WINDRIVE%/Program Files, /Applications, /usr/share etc).

When searching for it, it may be helpful to use regex, in case of different versions, so you don't have to add every application version by hand).

In Linux/Unix you could issue a **which** command to determine if the application is installed but I'm not sure how reliable it would be (i.e. the application binary is not reachable through the PATH variable).

Another (better) way would be to have a better knowledge about the OS programming and the OS's API and do a few system calls through JNI.

EDIT: Another approach might be to find the default program for the associated file's extension and check if it is the program you require (i.e. the user does not have ... say VLC Player associated with .mdf files). If you can get a list of all the programs associated with a file type, then you can just crawl through that list. Note that this might be less reliable than the previous solution as the program you need might not have the file type associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the PATH to find installed programs. Then you could search there for known programs.

If multiple programs are found or none, you could prompt the user. Prompting the user might be a good idea in general: Maybe the user has a 3rd solution and is able to connect to your program, or your search finds only one program xy while the search didn't yield yx, which is yx64 or yx2012 on his system.